# Each child in a list should have a unique key prop problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

Good day,
i'm experiencing  a slight problem. i want to have productdetails page where all the info is being displayed of the product. You can do that through clicking on the product link. but i'm getting the following err: Each child in a list should have a unique key prop problem

code homepage:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function Homescreen (props){
    return  <ul className="products" >
            { data.products.map(product => 
            <li key={product}>
            <div className="product-card">
              <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>
              <img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt="product"></img>
              </Link>
              <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}><h1 className="product-name">{product.name}</h1></Link>
              <p className="product-price">€{product.price}</p>
          <div className="product.rating">Stars ({product.numReviews})</div>
              <form method="post">
              <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            </li>
          )
         
        }     
  
    
</ul>

}

export default Homescreen;
```

code productpage:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function productScreen (props){

    console.log(props.match.params.id)
    const product = data.products.find(x=> x._id === props.match.params.id)
    return <div>
        <h1>product</h1>
    <div>
        <Link to="/">Back to products</Link>
    </div>
    <div className="productdetails">
        <div className="details-image">
            <img src={product.image} alt="product"></img>
        </div>
    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    <h4>{product.price}</h4>
<span>{product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)</span>
    </div>

</div>
  
 
}

export default productScreen;
```

Comment: You'll want to pass a unique value to each list item, not an object. Like a product.id if you have a unique id, or some other sort of unique identifier. React only allows Strings as keys.

Comment: If the products objects don't have a unique id, you could pass a second property, the index, and that should make it a unique value which you can use as the key property. But I think you already have a unique key, you can change this: <li key={product}> for this:   <li key={product._id}>

Comment: i fixed the err. But the detailspage won't show up. But i am clearly at the product page

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the [ReactJS Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component)

> A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

Therefore, a `key` can not be an object like the way you are using it here and will need to be a `String`. If your product does not have a unique identifier, then you can choose to use the `index` of your map method.

> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort:

```
// Example from the ReactjS Website

const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
// Only do this if items have no stable IDs
  <li key={index}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
<li key={product}>
```

To (assuming your id is unique)

```
<li key={product._id}>
```

The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings, you can check more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)